# Reward users for NOT asking a question

Tags: discussion

I ran into a problem this morning with templates in [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS) that I didn't have any idea how to solve. I started putting together a Stack Overflow question for it and in the process of writing the question, I solved it. I find this happens a lot with Stack Overflow. It's the same phenomenon as [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging); I guess that makes it Stack Overflow debugging.

I ended up not asking the question. Once I found the solution it wasn't such a good Stack Overflow question any more. It seems to me we might want to encourage that behavior - especially considering how much we don't like bad questions.

Comment: Certainly an interesting idea, but how in the world would you encourage it and reward it?

Comment: It has never once been discouraged.  And [blogged about](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) a long time ago.  All that changed is the "we're kind of jerks about it".  Happened when Jeff quit, not enough jerks left.

Comment: @psubsee2003: 5 rep to everyone who doesn't ask a question! Or, every time you don't ask a question, you get 5 rep! Or,... I'll just show myself out, thanks.

Comment: You get rewarded by *not* getting downvoted ;-)

Comment: We don't need positive reinforcement for *not* doing a bad behavior for which we already have negative reinforcement. @Marwie is joking, but he is completely correct here. In life, we don't give you some kind of reward for *not* committing crimes, we punish you when you *do* commit a crime.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine idea, and hardly deserves this amount of downvoting. The problem is how to implement it in a way that isn't trivial to game.

Answer (score 20):

If the question is interesting enough, you always have the option of [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) it.

If - on the other hand - the question just isn't a good SO question, I guess finding a solution to your problem should be enough of a reward.

Answer (score 6):

> I started putting together [a] question [...] and in the process of writing the question, I solved it.

It might sound alien, but this is the standard practice for a *lot* of developers. Running to Stack Overflow to ask a question and get an answer should be about the *last* thing you think about.

If I'd used the Ask A Question page for every rubber ducking session I've done in the past few years and this feature you're suggesting would be in place, I'd be a reputation millionaire.

Comment: [You have been haunt by shame](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/792066) [6 times](http://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster?tab=questions)

Comment: @Braiam four of which are reference / canonical questions. :*